# Error in swapping char array pointer elements of 2d pointer array in C

Tags: c, pointers

I cannot really understand the issue in my swap function:

```
void swap(char ***words, int w1, int w2){
    char *temp = malloc(sizeof(char*) * MAXWORD);
    temp = (*words)[w1];
    (*words)[w1] = (*words)[w2]
    (*words)[w2] = temp;
    free(temp);
}
```

it says

```
error: called object type 'char *' is not a function or
      function pointer
        (*words)[w2] = temp;
        ^
```

I created temporary pointer for my arrays of chars.. and then I assign this pointer instead of another pointer in 2D pointer array. What can be wrong here? Thank you

Comment: I don't see the necessity of a triple pointer or `malloc` and `free`. In fact, you're freeing `(*words)[w1]` and leaking what you `malloc`. Really, it should just be `void swap(char **words, int w1, int w2) {char *temp = words[w1]; words[w1] = words[w2]; words[w2] = temp;}`

Comment: `char *temp = malloc(sizeof(char*) * MAXWORD);` (memory leak) --> `char *temp;` and delete `free(temp);`

Comment: should it be free(*temp)?

Answer (score 2):

You forgot a semicolon, so this:

```
(*words)[w1] = (*words)[w2]
(*words)[w2] = temp;
```

is parsed as:

```
(*words)[w1] = (*words)[w2](*words)[w2] = temp;
```

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to place a semicolon between these two statements

```
(*words)[w1] = (*words)[w2] // <== absence of a semicolon
(*words)[w2] = temp;
```

However in any case your code has no sense because you at first allocate memory the address of which is stored in pointer `temp` and then you reassign the pointer.

```
char *temp = malloc(sizeof(char*) * MAXWORD);
temp = (*words)[w1];
```

So there is a memory leak.

Comment: so..how to cope with memory leak in this case? I am not really aware of this case. I just did how example shows in the Internet. But yes.. my situation seems different...

Comment: @PutinHuylo You need not to allocate memory pointed to by temp.